# Hibernate: save if not already in the table

Tags: hibernate

I have a table with several columns. Primary key is `id`, auto-generated.

Consider this code, which can be executed more than once:

```
  session.save(x);
```

The object `x` has the same contents, say if we run the program twice without any changes. As a result, the object appears twice in the table with different `id`s.

How can I modify this code to avoid duplicate insertions?

I considered using `session.get`, but that requires the knowledge of `id`.

I also considered setting up criteria from all fields of `x` other than `id`, but this is asking for trouble: one day I will add another column and forget to add it to criteria. Is there a good solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

if you do a

```
YourObject cachedX = (YourObject)session.merge(x);
```

cachedX will now have the generated Id.  Obviously you'll have to keep it around and you will most likely still need to come up with duplication rules.

Comment: generated id of what? There may or may not already be `x` in the table. Can you break it down: what the `id` will be if `x` is inserted for the first time? Second time?

Comment: the merge method in hibernate is defined as follows: 
"Copy the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the same identifier. If there is no persistent instance currently associated with the session, it will be loaded. If the given instance is unsaved, save a copy of and return it as a newly persistent instance."

Comment: Thanks, the explanation in your comment is very clear. But I am still guessing at the meaning of "Obviously you'll have to keep it around and you will most likely still need to come up with duplication rules". Can you explain what you mean here? Better yet, update the answer.